# Proving convexity of a $C^2$ function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I have to prove that, given $u\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C^0(\overline{\Omega})$, $\Omega$ open and bounded in $\mathbb R^n$ and $\lambda>0$ sufficiently small so that $2\lambda u<1$, the function
$$
H(u)=\frac{1}{\lambda}\left(1-\sqrt{1-2\lambda u}\right)
$$
is convex.

**My attempt.** Since
$$
H'(u)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2\lambda u}},
$$ 
then
$$
H''(u)=\frac{\lambda}{(1-2\lambda u)^{\frac{3}{2}}}> 0.
$$
Can we conclude that, since $H''(u)>0$, $H$ is convex?

Thank You

Comment: yes, that's correct.